# How to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_{2}{(f_{n})}}{(\log_{2}{n})^2}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

For any $n\in N$, such $f_{1}=1$, and such

$$f_{2n+1}=f_{2n}=f_{2n-1}+f_{n},$$

prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_{2}{(f_{n})}}{(\log_{2}{n})^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: This sequence is related to [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123).

Comment: oh,Thank you, This problem have solve?

Comment: Are you sure about the recurrence formula and the constant $1/2$? If I implemenent your definition as a function, it seems to converge to 0.3 (or at least osczilates about 0.3). The first values are 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 10, 10, 14, 14, 20, 20, 26, 26, 36 ...

Comment: yes, I think the constant is 1/2 is true. and you can http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/BasicRecurrenceRelationsSumsOfPowersOfTwo.aspx,,  or can see:http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=XT1-HjeXFgYC&pg=PA512&lpg=PA512&dq=number+of+partitions+of+2n+into+powers+of+2&source=bl&ots=KvBslV5cpk&sig=MGt581uakPYd5xTw2kUSTg1pTug&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=kaAUUqv6LaubigeGsYCQBg&ved=0CHkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=number%20of%20partitions%20of%202n%20into%20powers%20of%202&f=false

Comment: and  This problem have nice methods?  Thank you

Comment: I wonder how come all your friends (or is it only one?) constantly ask you such questions in mathematics...My friends, for one, ask me squat.

Comment: Hehe...I see, @GrahamHesketh, but in fact: no and no. :)

Comment: As @gammatester already did it, I check it with a C++ program: I got 0.323906. It looks like $\displaystyle{\sim 1/3}$.

Comment: This question is answered by papers cited on [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123): "On Mahler's partition problem" by de Bruijn 1948, and "On a special functional equation" by Mahler (JLMS 1940). Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\left(~\mbox{with}\quad z \in {\mathbb C}
               \quad\mbox{and}\quad
               \left\vert z \right\vert < 1~\right)$
$$
\Psi\left(z\right)
\equiv
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}\,{\rm f}_{n + 1}
=
\sum_{\sigma = \mp}\Psi_{\pm}\left(z\right)
\quad\mbox{where}\quad\left\vert%
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Psi_{-}\left(z\right) & \equiv & \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n + 1}\,{\rm f}_{2n + 2}
\\
\Psi_{+}\left(z\right) & \equiv & \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n}\,{\rm f}_{2n + 1}
\\
{\rm f}_{n}
& = &
\left.
{1 \over \left(n - 1\right)!}\,
{{\rm d}^{n - 1}\,\Psi\left(z\right) \over {\rm d}z^{n - 1}}
\right\vert_{z\ =\ 0}\,,
\quad
n > 1
\end{array}\right.
$$

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\\[5mm]
\Psi_{-}\left(z\right)
& = &
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n + 1}\,{\rm f}_{2n + 2}
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n + 1}\left\lbrack{\rm f}_{2n + 1} + {\rm f}_{n + 1}\right\rbrack
=
z\left\lbrack\Psi_{+}\left(z\right) + \Psi\left(z^{2}\right)\right\rbrack
\\
\Psi_{+}\left(z\right)
& = &
{\rm f}_{1} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n + 2}\,{\rm f}_{2n + 3}
=
1 + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n + 2}\,{\rm f}_{2n + 2}
=
1 + z\,\Psi_{-}\left(z\right)
\end{eqnarray}

$$
\Psi\left(z\right)
=
z\,\Psi\left(z\right) + 1 + z\,\Psi\left(z^{2}\right)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\left(1 - z\right)\,\Psi\left(z\right)
=
1 + z\,\Psi\left(z^{2}\right)
$$

$$
\Psi^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)
=
n\,\Psi^{\left(n - 1\right)}\left(0\right)
+
\left.n\,\Psi^{\left(n - 1\right)}\left(z^{2}\right)\right\vert_{z\ =\ 0}\,,
\qquad
n \geq 1
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rclrcl}
\Psi\left(z^{2}\right)
& = &
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n}\,{\rm f}_{n + 1}
,\quad&
\Psi\left(0\right) & = & {\rm f}_{1}
\\
\Psi''\left(z^{2}\right)
& = &
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n\left(2n - 1\right)z^{2n - 2}\,{\rm f}_{n + 1}
,\quad&
\Psi\left(0\right) & = & 2{\rm f}_{2}
\\
\Psi^{\left(\tt IV\right)}\left(z^{2}\right)
& = &
2\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}n\left(2n - 1\right)\left(2n - 2\right)\left(2n - 3\right)z^{2n - 4}\,
{\rm f}_{n + 1}
,\quad&
\Psi\left(0\right) & = & 16{\rm f}_{3}
\\
&\vdots& & \vdots&
\end{array}
$$

$$
\left.\Psi^{\left(2n\right)}\left(z^{2}\right)\right\vert_{z = 0}
=
{\rm f}_{n + 1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

\documentclass[winfonts,hyperref,a4paper]{ctexart}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=3.17cm,bottom=3.17cm]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}
\linespread{1.39}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\zihao{5}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pro}
Let$g(x)$be an strictly increasing continuous function in the
interval$[0,+\infty)$ and $g(0)=0$,$g(x)0$.If an
integer-valued finite terms sequence $P_{n}$satisfies the conditions
below (1) if $P_{i}=x$,then $P_{i+1}\le g^{-1}(x)$;(2)the last term
$P_{n}=n$.then the numbers of the sequence $P_{n}$
is$a_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^{[g(n)]} a_i$.

\end{pro}
\begin{proof}
If $P_{n}$has only one term,then $a_{n}\equiv 1$\

If$P_{n}$has at least two terms, then the second to last may be any
one of$[g(n)],[g(n)]-1,\cdots,1$. \
Thus $a_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^{[g(n)]} a_i$.

\end{proof}

\begin{pro}
$n\in N$,$f_{1}=1$,$f_{2n+1}=f_{2n}=f_{2n-1}+f_{n}$.

then

(0)$f_n$ is an integer-valued finite terms sequence and the last
term is $n$.Moreover ,$\forall n\le 1,f_(n+1)\le f_n$.

(1)$f_{n}=1+\sum_{i=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}f_i$.

(2)If  $f(x)=1+f_1x+f_2x^2+\cdots$ is the generating function of
$f_n$,then $f(x)$ is an unique solution to functional equation
of$f(x^2)=(1-x)f(x)$

(3)$f(x)=\Pi_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1-y^{2^k}}$.

(4)$f_n$ is numbers of nonnegative integer solutions to
$n=j_1+2j_2+4j_3+8j_4+16j_5+\cdots$.

(5)$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_{2}{(f_{n})}}{(\log_{2}{n})^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$
\end{pro}

\begin{proof}(0)Proposition 1 implies it.

(1)Notice\begin{align*}
f_{2n+1}=f_{2n}&=f_{2n-1}+f_{n}=f_{2n-2}+f_{n}
\\&=f_{2n-3}+f_{n-1}+f_n
\\&=f_{2n-5}+f_{n-2}+f_{n-1}+f_n
\\&=\cdots
\\&=f_1+f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_{n-1}+f_n
\\&=1+\sum_{k=1}^nf_k
\end{align*}

(2)Direct check.

\begin{align*}
(1+f_1x+f_2x^2+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+\cdots)&=1+(1+f_1)x+(1+f_1+f_2)x^2+\cdots
\\&=1+f_2x^2+f_4x^2+\cdots=1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_{2n}x^n
\\&=1+f_3x^2+f_4x^2+\cdots=1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_{2n+1}x^n
\end{align*}
$$f(\sqrt{x})=1+f_1\sqrt{x}+f_2(\sqrt{x})^2+\cdots$$
$$f(-\sqrt{x})=1-f_1\sqrt{x}+f_2(\sqrt{x})^2+\cdots$$
then$$\frac{f(x)}{1-x}=\frac{f(\sqrt{x})+f(-\sqrt{x})}{2}=\frac{f(\sqrt{x})-f(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

set $x=y^2$,then
$$\frac{f(y^2)}{1-y^2}=\frac{f(y)+f(-y)}{2}=\frac{f(y)-f(-y)}{2y}$$
Thus$f(-y)=\frac{1-y}{1+y}f(y)$,which implies $f$ satisfies
$f(y^2)=(1-y)f(y)$.

(3):By(2)\begin{align*}
f(y)&=\frac{f(y^{2^n})}{(1-y)(1-y^2)(1-y^4)\cdots(1-y^{2^{n-1}})}
\\&=\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{f(y^{2^n})}{\Pi_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-y^{2^i})}=\Pi_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1-y^{2^k}}
\end{align*}

(4)Because \begin{align*} f(y)=
\Pi_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}
y^{2^kj}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}2^{i-1}j_i=n}y^n
\end{align*}
Thus $f_n$ is numbers of nonnegative integer solutions to
$n=j_1+2j_2+4j_3+8j_4+16j_5+\cdots$. Obviously $f_n$ is increasing.

(5)Consider $n=2^k$,we try to give out an estimation of numbers of
nonnegative integer solutions to
$2^k=j_1+2j_2+4j_3+8j_4+\cdots+2^kj_{k+1}$.

Note $j_1$has at most$2^{k+1}$ choices ,$j_2$has at
most$2^{k}$choices,……,$j_{k+1}$has at most$2$choices.Then numbers
of nonnegative integer solutions have at most$2^{k+1}\cdot 2^k\cdot
\cdots\cdot 2=2^{\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}}$choices.

Thus $f_{2^k}\leq 2^{\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}}$,or $\log_2
f_{2^k}\leq\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}$,or
$\overline{\lim}_{k\to+\infty}\frac{\log_2 f_{2^k}}{k^2}\leq
\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly $\underline{\lim}_{k\to+\infty}\frac{\log_2
f_{2^k}}{k^2}\geq \frac{1}{2} $.

Thus $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{\log_2 f_{2^k}}{k^2}= \frac{1}{2}$.

If $2^k\leq n< 2^{k+1}$,$f_{2^k}\leq f_n\leq f_{2^{k+1}}$,then
$$\frac{\log_2 f_{2^k}}{k^2}\frac{k^2}{(\log_2 n)^2}\leq\frac{\log_2 f_n}{(\log_2 n)^2}\leq \frac{\log_2 f_{2^{k+1}}}{(k+1)^2}\frac{k^2}{(\log_2 n)^2}$$
let $n\to+\infty$,$k\to
\infty$,thus$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_{2}{(f_{n})}}{(\log_{2}{n})^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
\end{proof}
By the way ,the problem  has close connection with analytical number
theory(it can be proved in  analytical number theory way which is
quite concise.)Of course my friend tell me about the analytical
number theory approach.Could you tell me the original source or
links to the problem?I'm interested in it.Thanks for your problem.
\end{document}

Comment: You have a lot of unrendered $\LaTeX$ markup in your question that you don't need. It would look a lot better if you removed it. I mean things like "\end{document}."

Comment: @math110.Could you tell me the original source or links to the problem?I'm interested in it.Thanks for your problem.